# Does the iPhone GPS work in an airplane cruising between 30000-40000 feet?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, gps

I have a very basic question: if I enable GPS in my iPhone when in an airplane cruising at an altitude between 30000-40000 feet (roughly 9-12 km), will the GPS actually give valid data?

I read a couple of articles (linked below) but I'm still confused whether GPS will work or not.

1. https://www.quora.com/Does-mobile-GPS-work-onboard-airplanes
2. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/airplane-mode-does-not-disable-gps-is-it-safe-to-use-gps-in-flight

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

For most practical situations, GPS will work well enough for you to track your progress but not have great coverage (less than 2m accuracy) or accurate speed over ground readings from iOS.

From an antenna / physics perspective, you may have horrendous GPS reception since you are riding inside a mostly complete faraday cage. Even if you have your phone in a window, all the visible satellites might be in a configuration where [GPS is very poor or unable to generate a usable fix](http://www8.garmin.com/aboutGPS/).

Clearly, cruising altitude is generally one of the best places for GPS reception as long as the antenna is placed on a tip / extremity of the plane. You don't have multi path interference to speak of, no foliage, and no hills or buildings to interfere with a clear view horizon to horizon - not to mention that your altitude will let you see more than the normal "half the sky" visibility you get on the ground at best.

The phone hardware and iOS will certainly try to get you the best fix it can once you have the device out of Airplane mode. I know many pilots that report the iOS GPS in the cockpit is quite good / on par with the other consumer and even commercial navigation products.

Comment: I don't have an iphone, but my samsung phone's gps is very reliable while at cruising altitude (at least on a window seat, which I mostly use). I have tried this in many different flights, and the numbers shown by the phone's gps always agree with the plane's displayed data and map.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I agree - when you would get 2m to 10m accuracy of a fix with iPhone, you might get 10x the error, but if you are off by half a mile or more, does it really matter while you are tracking your flight? In practice, mobile GPS chipsets works just fine in any aircraft where humans are without pressure suits and even in many military aircraft.

Comment: Is the airplane really much of a faraday cage? My phone gets good enough reception on the ground that I can stream movies, which seems to me like the signals are getting in/out just fine.

Comment: @Cornstalks the GPS signal is very much weaker than your 3G/4G/wifi signal...

Comment: GPS still works in airplane mode.

Comment: I have wedged my Garmin Nuvi, Galaxy S and iPhone between the window shade and the window: this enables a GPS device to receive the required signals to calculate position.  While there is no reference other than visual landmarks, I observed 'good enough' poistion reporting \ speed.

Answer (score 12):

Domestic Satellite Navigation systems usually include limitations as a  security measure.  [The general rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoCom#Legacy) is that nothing off the shelf should be able to assist in the creation of a guided missile.

To that end most, if not all, civilian GPS units will fail or work poorly if any of the following conditions are met:

- High Altitude - Once you are higher than a mountain you are no longer a normal civilian user.  This limit is usually very high though (50,000ft), more commonly edge of space rather than domestic airline altitudes.
- High Speed - If you are doing more than one or two hundred miles an hour you are probably a high speed vehicle or missile.  That being said the limit could be set well above the speed of sound so that civilian aircraft are unlikely to hit it.
- High Dynamics - If you are performing high speed turns you might be a missile or air-craft evading attack.  It is usually not possible for commercial passenger aircraft to perform manoeuvres that trigger these limits though.

You may find that this causes an issue when using your phone on-board an aircraft.  I use to build test equipment for GNSS systems and would often find GPS units behaving strangely if I started to simulate any of the above conditions.

Poor reception due to the fuselage is also a possibility.  To test if this is the limiting factor, rather than the security measures, simply try using your phone's GPS within the plane while it is on the ground before take-off.  If you can get a position fix before take-off but struggle once in flight it will be the security measures limiting you.  I would expect most phones to not be limited by this though.  If you can use it inside a bus or train without being by a window I would expect the shielding and signal levels to be similar to inside a aeroplane.

Comment: How would a GPS system technically prevent a fast-moving or fast accelerating receiver from working? GPS is (or can be used) entirely passively; the sender has no way of knowing who receives it, and under which conditions. Do you have references?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider is referring to CoCom regulations for hardware manufacturing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoCom

Comment: Even more so than security measures, GPS receivers intended for typical civilian use are designed with that use case in mind. Their signal processing is configured such that it will provide good performance (i.e. high tracking accuracy) in typical user scenarios (moving at car speeds or less, on the ground). High dynamics, altitude, or speed can all result in poor performance, even if not by specific security-based design, by nature of the receiver processes that are tuned for "normal" conditions.

Comment: @StephenP. I see; the limitation is in the receiver. Wikipedia reports the limits as 1900 km/h and 18,000 meters though, both beyond current civil aeronautics. Since CoCom (-successors) concern exports out of the US, GPS receivers elsewhere are not impacted, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Restrictions_on_civilian_use

Comment: Great information - can you / anyone edit this post to make it relevant to either iOS software or apple hardware so that it's more relevant to the question at hand (less than 59,000 ft altitude and less than 1200 mph)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: If the right people find out that you are manufacturing a GPS that doesn't turn itself off in the right conditions you will be in serious trouble. The kind of trouble where a good lawyer is not going to help.

Comment: @gnasher729 Perhaps 30 years ago. Did you even do the most basic research? cf. http://www.directindustry.com/prod/sbg-systems/product-102401-1037165.html

Comment: You say if ANY of the conditions are met, but many manufacturers use the rule that both speed and altitude limits must be exceeded.  GPS is often used in amateur ballooning above 60000 feet.  I cannot find information on how the iphone GPS chipset behaves.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Many smart manufacturers put in the USA export limits into their hardware to keep them safe to sell devices to the USA that then might be integrated into something else and exported again. When an economy is as important as the USA to global commerce there laws tend to apply well beyond their borders. That said you can get firmware that will remove those limits, but you'll need to convince the manufacturer that you aren't making weapons and that you really need it.

Comment: @LovesTha Just to reiterate: A passenger plane does noot meet *either* of the criteria for the ITAR restrictions to kick in (too [s]low), and some of the answers here contain first-hand accounts of off-the shelf GPS devices, including apple products, working in-flight. (Others provide first-hand accounts of them *not* working, sure; that can have all sorts of reasons, but ITAR is not one of them.)

Comment: @bmike I think that to fulfil your request of making this more specific to "iOS software or apple hardware" I would need to test every Apple supplied phone handset.  The limitations are likely to vary between handsets as they will contain different GPS/GNSS receivers.  On top of that different firmware images may have different assumptions about the largest values that will be seen for altitude and speed.  This may explain some of the variation in reported behaviour.

Comment: My automotive GPS reports speeds of 400+ mph in commercial aircraft.    While it is possible for the receiver algorithm to prevent calculations associated with military dynamics, it would be a travesty to hobble the users

Answer (score 4):

This is from a fact, on my last trip, I was trying to see how fast the airplane was travelling using Speedometer app on iPhone 5c. It didn't work.

Speedometer doesn't show location, so I tried Strava. It also didn't show speed, but it's showing that the position on map jumped occasionally.

I don't think it's GPS signal issue, I brought a Garmin bike computer one time and it recorded the flight just fine. I still have the records of a couple of flights, it's interesting to see that planes don't just take the shortest path. The only thing that didn't look right was the altitude, since it's using barometer and the cabin is pressurised.

Comment: It's interesting that it got the altitude wrong. GPS is a 3D system (actually 4D, as it solves for time offset as well), and normally the height would be calculated from the GPS loci. But if the receiver can only "see" 3 satellites "good" software will guess the height - I'm guessing that's what Garmin did. The down-side of that is that guessing wrong (as it did) will introduce positional errors...

Comment: @Grimxn: Many GPS devices also have a pressure-based altimeter.  It's sometimes a selectable setting whether the altitude readout is based on that or the GPS data.  I believe the altimeter is better at detecting small altitude changes.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It will indeed be - but my point was that if a receiver can see four or more satellites, it will at least be able to estimate height as well as time offset and 2D horizontal position, but if it could only see three satellites (quite likely inside an aircraft), it would use the altimeter (wrongly, in this case) to constrain the Z in the solution...

Comment: I just look at the record again and I think less accurate is more correct, since the cabin pressure is more constant. There were small dips after the planes landed.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but you must hold the phone at the window. And sometimes it takes plenty of time to fix the signal.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to an iPhone specifically, but an iPad Air 2 works just fine as long as I'm in a window seat. I use [ForeFlight](https://www.foreflight.com/), software used for navigating while flying, all the time during commercial flights when a passenger. During the climb/descent a turn might throw it off and it'll take a few seconds to reacquire the signal, and it might require holding it right to the window to reacquire position. But in cruise, once it's got a position, I can leave it on the tray table and it'll happily show position, ground speed, and GPS-computed altitude for a half hour or more without issues. The altitude is of course slightly off because when you're in cruise the plane is flying not at a fixed "feet" altitude but rather at a given [flight level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level).

Answer (score 0):

GPS itself works very well even in space. As the other answers have already mentioned the problem with low signal inside the plane is probably the biggest problem you will face.

However, all GPS receivers are limited to speeds and altitudes.

See http://gizmodo.com/5824905/your-gps-doesnt-work-at-mach-2-because-its-afraid-youre-a-soviet-spy

Comment: The fear is not that you are a spy, but a high speed nuclear missile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture that I have taken in the plane using my iPhone 6. It is the IGO application on the screen. I do not know the exact altitude but it was really high. You can see our ground speed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GPS was designed for use in space and at high altitudes. Get close to a window and it will work (iPhone 5s, SE, iPad 2, iOS 9, 10).

You should turn off WiFi and cellular data, because the iPhone will also use cell-phone and WiFi signals to triangulate the position. These may be stronger than GPS but may be far off and stationary on the ground. If you try recording the GPS track, it will be jumpy because of this effect. The effect may be worse, if you have in-flight WiFi which is tied to some location on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

You iPhone GPS works fine in flight mode, the main limiting factor is the Faraday cage effect which will limit your view of the sky if not in a window seat. even in a window seat you may not always have a clear view of the 4 satelites required. Next time you are on a plane in a window seat try PocketGPS for iPhone which is free and has no adds. There should be no hight restrictions below 50,000 feet and the speed of a commercial aircraft will also be well within that allowed by GPS.

Answer (score 0):

I've been happily using my iPhone GPS while flying in Europe without a problem, mainly to ID my photos. But here's a curious sudden change. I often fly from Switzerland to southern Spain and have been able to get clear IDs for the entire flight. This week it worked fine over Switzerland and France but all GPS ID's stopped as soon as we entered Spanish airspace and my photos show them once again only when we were on the ground. I changed no settings during the flight. So I'm assuming Spain has suddenly put new security measures into place. I wonder if other countries are doing the same. It's the only explanation I can think of.